# ListView deprecated - how to remove it from my project?

Tags: react-native, npm

ListView has been deprecated in react native. How do I remove all references to it in my project?? I am no longer even using it in my code, but I am still getting an error when I try to build my React Native project that reads...

```
Invariant Violation: ListView has been removed from React Native.
```

Why am I getting this error if no where in my project do I use ListView?

When I run the command "npm ls react-native-listview", I get the following output...

```
/Users/user/myProject/myApp
└── (empty)
```

Comment: Is one of your dependencies using it? Try removing suspect deps to see if it works.

Comment: Do you know of any ways to see all of the dependencies using a given module? It is an expo project in VS Code

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. If a module provides a list-type functionality, you can look there first. I'm unfamiliar with expo, only having done the ejected kind.